# Using UpdatePanel for progress indication

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, blockui

I just red this article http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/ 
It's about adding BlockUI on server-side click.

Here we used UpdatePanel. 
So i have few questions :

- Is it possible to use UpdatePanel without ScriptManager?
- Can i add one UpdatePanel to Master Page and use it on every button click?

My idea is to add some class to button, on click on which i want to show blockUI and use next code :

```
$('.btn-busy').click(function () {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#img-loader'),
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '5px',
            'background-color': 'transparent',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .6,
            color: '#fff',
            cursor: 'wait'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code actually do its job? if so, you only want to know the answer to the two questions?

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta, my code seems to be ok but i don't know if in all cases. So i try to find some other solutions in net to be sure that everything is ok. And using UpdatePanel seems to be that solution that i try to find. And questions - because i don't know how properly add UpdatePanel into my code

Comment: That code will work without/outside an UpdatePanel. It only depends on the jQuery and BlockUI libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use UpdatePanel without ScriptManager?

No, it's not.

> Can I add one UpdatePanel to Master Page and use it on every button
>   click?

Yes, however you're setting yourself up for disaster. Some controls don't work well in `UpdatePanel`, and you'll find yourself having all sorts of difficult to debug issues with the site. If you're going to use an `UpdatePanel` (and I recommend you don't) then you should have it as close to the controls that need it as possible in order to minimize those issues.